# Magento 1.7 Add Multiple Attributes to Collection Filter

Tags: magento, collections

In my function that grabs a collection of products, I am going to filter by an unknown number of attributes so I cant hardcode them in. My function is the one below:

```
public function getAssociatedProducts()
    {

        $parameters = $this->getRequest()->getPost();               
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parameters['parent_id']);
        $grouped = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped');


        $collection = $grouped->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter($grouped->getStoreFilter($product))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $grouped->getStatusFilters($product)));          
            // I need to do another addAttributeToFilter on this collection for the $parameters variable above. But the number of paramters I will need to check is unknown.


        return $collection;

    }
```

Can addAttributeToFilter handle an array of attributes? The number of attributes that the $parameters variable will bring is unknown and I can only figure out how to do them one at a time but I need it to be flexible enough to handle adding up to 10 attributes to the filter.

Thank you!

I should add that the array of paramters might look like this:

```
galco_weapon_list => 3602,
product_color => 1595,
weapon_draw_hand => 2700
```

The array above will always be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass an `array` as first parameter to `addAttributeToFilter()`, Magento will assume you want to build an `OR` construct. So no, you can't pass different attributes all at once.

If you pass a `string` (or instanceof `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract`), Magento assumes you want the passed attribute to be `AND`ed.

Looking at your post, I think your goal is to `AND` some filters, where you don't know which attributes will come, but they all need to be equal to their given value.

Assuming the keys in `$parameters` match the attributes names, you can achieve this by inserting a loop before returning and loop thru your `$parameters` array.

Do your sanitizing/validation as usual per attribute, then add an `addAttributeToFilter()` call per iteration, e.g. something like this:

```
:

foreach ($parameters as $k => $v) {

    // ... sanitizing/validation code here ...

    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($k, $v);

}

return $collection;
```

Comment: Hi Jurgen, thank you for your answer. Originally I had tried something similar but your answer made me realize that I missed something. Your method works. However, there are situations in which it doesnt work and maybe you can help me. All of my attributes are multiselect. When a product only has one of an attribute select this works because it treats it as equals. When the product has more than one of a particular attribute, it returns null. How do I do the oppopsite of this $collection->addAttributeToFilter($code, array('in' => $value)) where I want to see if the value is in the multiselect?

Comment: I just tried this and it works. $collection->addAttributeToFilter($code, array('like' => '%'.$value.'%')); However, I wonder about accuracy using wildcards.

Comment: You can simply change the code to check the data type of `$v` first and use different variants of `addAttributeToFilter()` accordingly. If `$v` is an `array`, use `addAttributeToFilter($k, array('in', $v))`, and so on...